# PhoneGap Build Get App Version inside About Us Page

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I've built an About Us page of the app and I want to include the app version defined in the config.xml. Therefore, I want it to get version automatically rather then inserting it manually.

```
    <script type="text/ons-template" id="about.html">
<ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="sNavigator"> 
<ons-page id="page-about">
   <ons-toolbar>     

    <div class="left">
     <ons-toolbar-button onclick="setHome();">
        <ons-icon icon="fa-chevron-left"></ons-icon>
     </ons-toolbar-button>        
    </div> 

    <div class="center white"><span id="search-text" class="trn" data-trn-key="settings">About Us</span></div>                  
   </ons-toolbar>

    <div class="about-page wrapper center">     

    <img src="css/images/logo2.png" width="40%" class="logo-about" alt="">

    <p>App Application</p>
    <strong> **+version+** </strong>

    <p>Owner &amp; Founder</p>
    <strong> XXXXX</strong>

    <p>Website</p>
    <strong> www.domain.com</strong>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <p>Developed &amp; Designed by</p>
    <strong>Developer</strong>

    </div><!--End Homepage -->


  </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>  
</script>
```

Kindly advise, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

@WiTon
As with anything with Cordova/Phonegap, use a [plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/) and search for "[app version](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=app%20version)".

My favorite is [cordova-plugin-appversion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-appversion). Here is a [test app](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/PGBP-AppVersion) that works with *[Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com)*.

Comment: thanks for the answer I'll work on it. Also I added this  `cordova.getAppVersion(function (version) {
    alert(version);
 });` in the app.js and I'll call it from the html page

Comment: out of the box do you advise for plugin that shows slide-menu when clicking on the menu button on some Android Smartphones like Samsung?

Comment: If the answer worked for you, I would appreciate you marking the answer "accepted". Menu buttons are no longer available for Android. It is [not required and is deprecated](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply to be honest I tried to use the same test app exactly but didn't work. I'll update my question with what I did hopefully you can help me from there.

Comment: What do you mean "I tried to use the same test app exactly but didn't work."? I've tested the app it works fine? What version of Android are you testing on? FWIW: if you are testing on iOS, you need to reBuild for your device.